# How to display data from server in handlebar template?

Tags: node.js, ckeditor, handlebars.js

I am using nodejs as my backend service and handlebar templating engine as a frontend. And i am using ckeditor in some of the textboxes. I can easily save my form to the server but the main problem is whenever i try to display the data saved from those textboxes, it dispalys with html tags like

```
<h1>This is a title</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph</p>
```

I just want to display a normal text, paragraphs and lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation http://handlebarsjs.com/#html-escaping :

> Handlebars HTML-escapes values returned by a {{expression}}. If you
>   don't want Handlebars to escape a value, use the "triple-stash", {{{.

You have to use a triple-stash {{{}}} around your data in order to display what you want.

Take a look also to the use of handlebar helpers ins the documentation :

> Handlebars will not escape a Handlebars.SafeString. If you write a
>   helper that generates its own HTML, you will usually want to return a
>   new Handlebars.SafeString(result). In such a circumstance, you will
>   want to manually escape parameters.